# getting Invalid Merchant or Merchant doesn't exist! with payflow when opening payflow link

Tags: spring-boot, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro, payflowlink

I am referring to this article : https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-integrate-my-website-with-payflow-link-(basic)-ts1245

We are performing a test transaction on a payflow account, using html/javascript code and for that we are passing test data for the following fields: LOGIN, PARTNER, AMOUNT, TYPE.

On submit we are posting the above data to https://payflowlink.paypal.com. It is returning the following error message:

> Error: Invalid Merchant or Merchant doesn't exist!

What mistake am I making?

Also, I want to know that the above approach is correct for payflow transactions using a custom website integration?

Answer (score 0):

If this is not for a live transaction, use https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com

> we are passing test data for below fields LOGIN, PARTNER,AMOUNT,TYPE.

Your question should include the form you are using and the data you are passing, since invalid data here may be precisely the problem.

---

Regardless, why are you using the 15+ year-old Payflow Link instead of the much newer and nicer [standard PayPal checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) with its black Debit or Credit Card button? ....

[image]

Comment: Thanks Preston PHX but this is our requirement using payflow we need to perform transactions

Comment: also can you please help me that how can we perform this using rest API. so, we can just enter credit card details on front side and pass it to back side then using rest payflow API
to perform transaction ?

Comment: There is no REST API for Payflow, it is very old and uses an NVP API (with optional length tags in brackets). Is your intention to use Payflow Link hosted pages or transparent redirect, or not? If you are using those pages or transparent redirect, you only need the Payflow API to get a secure token. If you are not using those pages and not using transparent redirect, then a credit card can be processed with the Payflow API, but this is not secure and PCI (credit card companies) requires SAQ type "D" https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pci_security/completing_self_assessment